Apk built from Android Studio is too large in size due to Font
I am building a APK from android studio with very simple functions and serveral GUI activities.
The apk is quite large and i found that fonts are taking too much space even I am sure that, I am not using them.  Can anyone help on how to remove those fonts dependencies from building APK?
After carefully looking at the APK analysis, we found that fontsUsedinSDK.txt contains all the fonts i have never imported or used.
I did not have any idea to solve this i was hoping someone could give a hand.

Apk analysis information :
Dependencies from build.gradle:
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'


Seems like these fonts are getting added by the gradle libraries you are using. Consider sharing the app gradle file. So that someone may help you.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I can not add gradle file or code block in the body of post

In your build.dradle enable code shrinking
buildTypes {
 release {
  isMinifyEnabled = true
  isShrinkResources = true
  proguardFiles(
     getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
 }
}

And set the proguard rules also

Thank you for the help, but it does not reduce the APK size

You have probably specified a text style somewhere (in xml or programmatically) that caused to include these, you seem to have fonts for about 8 languages included.
You could carefully specify a font in any part that uses text, so that you only include the fonts needed for one targeted language. There are single language versions available of the NotoSans Font
See answer on specifying your own fonts.
You could also use the Downloadable Font feature of Android possibly to reduce your App Size.
